# Hadoop Mapreduce : values to reducer are in reverse order

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I will be doing the following in a much bigger file. for now,I have an example input file with the following values.

```
1000,SMITH,JERRY
1001,JOHN,TIA
1002,TWAIN,MARK
1003,HARDY,DENNIS
1004,CHILD,JACK
1005,CHILD,NORTON
1006,DAVIS,JENNY
1007,DAVIS,KAREN
1008,MIKE,JOHN
1009,DENNIS,SHERIN
```

now what i am doing is running a mapreduce job to encrypt the last name of each record and write back an output. and i am using the mapper partition number as the key and the modified text as value.

so the output from mapper will be,

```
0   1000,Mj4oJyk=,,JERRY
0   1001,KzwpPQ,TIA
0   1002,NSQgOi8,MARK
0   1003,KTIzNzg,DENNIS
0   1004,IjsoPyU,JACK
0   1005,IjsoPyU,NORTON
0   1006,JTI3OjI,JENNY
0   1007,JTI3OjI,KAREN
0   1008,LDoqNg,JOHN
0   1009,JTYvPSgg,SHERIN
```

I don't want any sorting to be done.I also use a reducer because, in case of a larger file, there will be multiple mappers and if no reducer, multiple output files will be written. so i use a single reduce to merge values from all mappers and write to single file.
now the input values to reducer comes in reversed order and in the order from mapper. it is like the following,

```
1009,JTYvPSgg,SHERIN
1008,LDoqNg==,JOHN
1007,JTI3OjI=,KAREN
1006,JTI3OjI=,JENNY
1005,IjsoPyU=,NORTON
1004,IjsoPyU=,JACK
1003,KTIzNzg=,DENNIS
1002,NSQgOi8=,MARK
1001,KzwpPQ==,TIA
1000,Mj4oJyk=,JERRY
```

Why is it reversing the order? and how can i maintain the same order from mapper? any suggestions will be helpfull

**EDIT 1 :**

the Driver code is,

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
Job job = Job.getInstance(conf);
    job.setJobName("encrypt");
    job.setJarByClass(TestDriver.class);
    job.setMapperClass(TestMap.class);
    job.setNumReduceTasks(1);
    job.setReducerClass(TestReduce.class);
    job.setMapOutputKeyClass(IntWritable.class);
    job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);
     job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
     job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(hdfsInputPath));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(hdfsOutputPath));
System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
```

the mapper code is,

```
        inputValues = value.toString().split(",");
        stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        TaskID taskId = context.getTaskAttemptID().getTaskID();
        int partition = taskId.getId();

 // the mask(inputvalue) method is called to encrypt input values and write to stringbuilder in appropriate format
        mask(inputvalues);
        context.write(new IntWritable(partition), new Text(stringBuilder.toString()));
```

The reducer code is,

```
       for(Text value : values) {
        context.write(new Text(value), null);
       }
```

Comment: Please share your code mapper and reducer codes. Till i know framework sorts the outputs of the maps on keys and then pass on to reducer task, due to this might be getting reversed.

Answer (score 0):

The base idea of MapReduce is that the order in which things are done is irrelevant. 
So you cannot (and do not need to) control the order in which

- the input records go through the mappers.
- the key and related values go through the reducers.

The only thing you can control is the order in which the values are placed in the iterator that is made available in the reducer.

For that you can use the `Object key` to maintain the order of values.
The LongWritable part (or the key) is the position of the line in the file (Not line number, but position from start of file). 
You can use that part to keep track of which line was first.

Then your mapper code will be changed to

```
protected void map(Object key, Text value, Mapper<Object, Text, LongWritable, Text>.Context context)
        throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    inputValues = value.toString().split(",");
    stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    mask(inputValues);
    // the mask(inputvalue) method is called to encrypt input values and write to stringbuilder in appropriate format
    context.write(new LongWritable(((LongWritable) key).get()), value);

}
```

Note: you can change all `IntWritable` to `LongWritable` in your code but be careful.

Answer (score 0):

```
    inputValues = value.toString().split(",");
    stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    TaskID taskId = context.getTaskAttemptID().getTaskID();
    //preserve the number value for sorting
    IntWritable idNumber = new IntWritable(Integer.parseInt(inputValue[0])

    // the mask(inputvalue) method is called to encrypt input values and write to stringbuilder in appropriate format
    mask(inputvalues);
    context.write(idNumber, new Text(stringBuilder.toString()));
```

I made some assumptions because you did not have the full code of the mapper. I assumed that `inputValues` was a string array due to the `toString()` output. The first value of the array should be the number value from your input, however it is now a string. You must convert the number back to `IntWritable` to match what your mapper is emitting `IntWritable,Text`. The hadoop framework will sort by key and with the key being of type `IntWritable` it will sort in ascending order. The code you provided is using the task ID and from reading the API https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/TaskAttemptID.html#getTaskID()  It was unclear whether this would provide an order to your values as you desired. To control the order of output I would recommend using the first value of your string array and convert to IntWritable. I don't know if this violates your intent to mask the `inputValues`.

*EDIT*

To follow up with your comment. You can simply multiply the `partition` by `-1` this will cause the hadoop framework to reverse the order.

```
int partition = -1*taskId.getId();
```

Comment: what you said could be done. but like i mentioned earlier, the data i gave was just an example. In real cases, the data i would be using will not always have an id column. so, I cant go with that approach ! But thanks anyway for the solution. This might be really usefull for another case im looking into :)

Comment: Another way to reverse the order would be to multiply the `int partition *-1` before emitting it from the mapper. This will cause the hadoop framework to sort it in the reverse order.